# Defining Category of Problems

Tags: logic, category-theory

Let $\left\{\Pi_i\right\}_{i \in I}$ be a family of problems. Let problem $\Pi_i$ have solution $u_i$ lying in some solution space $X_i$. I am interested in making this set into a category. Is it meaningful to define morphisms between problems as follows?

Define a morphism $f_{ij}:\Pi_i \rightarrow \Pi_j$ if there exists a map $\sigma: X_i \rightarrow X_j$ such that $u_j = \sigma(u_i)$.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are interested in making this set into a category... for what purpose? Certainly this is a sensible definition, but whether it will actually help you do anything depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I want to be able to define products of problems: decomposing a bigger problem to a set of smaller ones.

Comment: This sounds a bit like the [category of contexts](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/context).

Comment: @Zhen: this is very interesting.

Comment: What does a "problem" mean here?

Comment: @Henning: I am thinking of a well-defined mathematical class of problems. For example: the matrix inversion. In that case each $\Pi_i$ would be indexed by a nonsingular matrix.

Comment: Is there any formal difference between "problem" and "function", then? If not, what makes a function qualify as a "problem"?

Comment: @Henning: Excellent point. Indeed, i am also thinking of $\Pi_i$ as a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition as it stands seems to be too liberal to be really useful; since it only depends on one particular value of $\sigma$, you get lots of morphisms everywhere, so you won't really be capturing any notion of composing solutions.

I *suspect* that what you'll really want to look into is *cartesian closed categories*, which have a big name in theoretical computer science as models of *typed lambda calculi*. This will allow you to speak about composition of computable functions, et ceteral. It might be possible to define, say, a category of polynomial-time reductions using this framework (though some delicate care would be needed to avoid the full power of the lambda calculus leaking through to the problem domain).

Comment: Excellent hint. In fact i want my morphisms to be such that they do not depend on the particular values of the solutions. In other words, i have a general rule to maps one solution to the other. How do i express this more formally?